# wordpress widget title not showing up "correctly"

Tags: php, html, wordpress, coding-style, widget

I have this wordpress theme on my website and all the widgets that are from the theme itself use some different style for the title I'm talking about the font color, you can see it on the following link http://www.bucatepealese.ro/retete/orez-cu-dovlecel/. What I'm trying to do is to make somehow all my widget titles to look the same. Is there a way I could make the theme force all the widget titles to use same styling? or even if I'll have to go through each of the plugins I'm using and add some code to them to make the title look this way. That would work too. Any ideas ? Thanks in advance, hopefully one of you will be able to help me or at least point me in the right direction. And I hope you can understand what I mean, I've tried to explain it the best I could.
I've also attached the code my theme's widget use to make the title look like this. Basically I want all the titles to use 1 color for my first word and another one for the other words.

I think this is what my theme's widget use for that title

```
    if($title):
    $temp_title = explode(' ',$title);
    $first_letter = $temp_title[0];
    unset($temp_title[0]);
    $title_new = implode(' ', $temp_title);
    $title = $first_letter.' <span>'.$title_new.'</span>';
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code you found there is working for me. The only reason why it would not work is if $title was not set.

Another way you could do it is by wrapping the text you want to be green in  tags in the wordpress title editor, it's dirty but it will get the job done.

PHP:

```
$title = 'Abonează-te la Newsletter!';

if($title)
{
    $temp_title = explode(' ',$title);
    $first_word = $temp_title[0];
    unset($temp_title[0]);
    $title_new = implode(' ', $temp_title);
    $title = $first_word.' <span>'.$title_new.'</span>';
    echo($title);
};
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work for me, I've tried adding this code in other widgets, for example the first one from that page, the facebook like box and it won't modify the title, tried with both codes, the one you posted and the one I've found on my theme's widgets. I'm not really sure what you meant by the other way, to add font color tags in the wordpress editor? if that's what you mean, for some reason after I do that and press the save button, wordpress removes the tags and only leaves the title so it won't do anything. - Thank you for helping me, really appreciate it :)

Comment: also this is how it looks after i add this code in the newsletter sign up widget http://i59.tinypic.com/33bicyh.jpg